# Nothing in the feature box QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

When I add a feature, the feature attribute box comes up but it has nothing in it...completely blank, no fields. It used to come up but stopped. I have re-installed it but the same thing occurs.

[image]

Comment: If you leave the Edit mode of the layer, and zoom to the extent of the roads layer, do you get any information in the attribute table? Do you see the attribute table columns in Rightclick on the layer -> properties, Fields tab?

Comment: Yeah..sure....all the attributes I put in are still there in tables and columns. when i digitise a part and right click, usually the feature box would pop up and i would input a number id and name. but now...it's just a blank box